# android repeater-like functionality

Tags: android, layout, repeater, row

is there any type of 'repeater' type functionality in android?  I have a relative layout (inside a row in a listview) and inside that I'd like to have a series of TextViews be displayed one after the other (as if they are child rows in the listview row).  The issue is that the number of those "child rows" will vary.  is there any way to do this, or should i just create the TextView objects in code, and programatically add them to a linear or table layout?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing (besides ListView/ListAdapter, naturally) that I can think of offhand is [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) and [ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory.html), but there's really nothing magical there: it's an interface that you can call to get a view.

Since it's only one line to get a view and add it to your current hierarchy anyways, though (`View.inflate(context, R.layout.somelayout, myContainerViewGroup)`) it feels silly to go with something heavier, but if you feel better wrapping that up in a Factory of some sort, check the AOSP [source for ViewSwitcher](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.java;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 0):

One option is TextViews support [Multi-line](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:minLines) text. So you could create the text with a StringBuilder using "\n" for new lines, and not have to worry about multiple text views.

Comment: hmmm, that does sound like a nice solution.  the only issue is that i need each 'child row' to appear to be in a light blue box, with a white separation in between each 'row'